# Защита через cookies

Tags: php, cookie

Друзья делаю голосовалку!

Защиту по IP сделал! Но ее мало - нужна защита в кукисах!

Голосовалка содержит категории и сами организации!

Организации выводяться по ссылке в виде: site.ru/index.php?org_id=Категория

Мне нужно что бы голосовать можно было только 1 раз в 1 категории, при переходе в другую - так же 1 раз!

У меня запивываются куки - но голосовать можно только 1 раз вообще - если перейти в другие категории то там уже голосовать нельзя, проголосовав до этого где-то!

Вот можно как то привязать чтение кукисов к ссылке - что бы они проверялись у определенных категориях - site.ru/index.php?org_id=Категория??

Comment: так пиши в куки и ид голосования

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['site.ru/index.php?org_id=Категория'])){
    // учитываем голос и т.д
    ...
    // ставим куку на эту категорию, в значение можно что-то еще прописать, для удобства
    setcookie('site.ru/index.php?org_id=Категория','anystring');
}
```

При  работе с куками средствами PHP [есть ряд особенностей](http://www.php.su/functions/?setcookie), это также нужно учесть.

Answer (score 0):

куки не самая топ защита)))) защиты по ипу достаточно)

Answer (score 0):

> Организации выводяться по ссылке в виде: site.ru/index.php?org_id=Категория
>
> Мне нужно что бы голосовать можно было только 1 раз в 1 категории,
> при переходе в другую - так же 1 раз!

решение:

```
if ( !isset($_COOKIE['org_id'.Категория]) ) {
    // разрешаем голосовать 1 раз, только если куки нет
    // ......
    // ставим куку на месяц на указанный урл для указанного сайта
    setcookie('org_id'.Категория, 'Голо совал!', time() + (86400 * 30), 'index.php?org_id='.Категория, 'site.ru');
}
```

подробнее здесь http://www.php.su/setcookie()